# Can't get active link highlight on the menu

Tags: css

I have simple menu but I'm unable to highlight the active menu item when browsing the site.

The code is

```
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.topnav a {
  float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #1d297b;
    border: 1px solid #1d297b;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Luxia-Display";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.topnav a:hover, .topnav a.active {
    color: #000 !important;
    border-color: #dacd9d !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

And JS part

```
$('.topnav .topnav-centered a').on('click', function() {
   $('.topnav .topnav-centered a').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Here is the fiddle that I have created for showcase: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/grev2amn/)

Comment: In the Fiddle, jQuery is not included. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0x5f49zm/) where I have included jQuery.

Comment: Agree that there is no jQuery references, on top of that the fiddle originally posted and code posted in question are different. Fiddle has css for an active pseudo-class: `.topnav a:active` and code above has css for `.topnav a.active`.

Comment: Yes, and I have tried with the example below. They are working on the fiddle but not on the actual site. The difference is that I have also bootstrap js and prefixfree.min.js as I've explained below. Even with them added to the fiddle still works there.

Comment: It is working when the link is `<a href="#">Link</a>` but when I put actual link like `<a hreg="page.php"> Page </a>` it's not working anymore

Answer (score 3):

Just add `jQuery`
The error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` means that no `jQuery` is present.

```js
$('.topnav .topnav-centered a').on('click', function() {
   $('.topnav .topnav-centered a').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.topnav a {
  float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #1d297b;
    border: 1px solid #1d297b;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Luxia-Display";
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.topnav a:hover, .topnav a.active {
    color: #000 !important;
    border-color: #dacd9d !important;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, I see what's wrong on my fiddle but stil doesn't work when I add this to the actual site. Only the hover is working. There is nothing in the console of the browser for js errors. Strange

Comment: JSfiddles are for testing and coding purposes, this means normally that if you take it 1 on 1 to your own code, it should work. In your case it could be that you have more code on your page. Do you have more JS code or is this it?

Comment: Yes, I have - bootstrap js and prefixfree.min.js. But I have tried with them on the JSFiddle and there still works.

Comment: @Goro the code you posted in the question is different to the code posted in the fiddle. Check the css around `active`, you have used a pseudo-class in your fiddle and not a class.

Comment: @MattFricker, you're right but I have tried with the exact setup from this answer which is correct and still not working on my side

Comment: What I'm noticing on the console is that it is adding `class="active"` and `class=""` to the links for second and then removes it when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: I see you have updated the fiddle in terms of the active class. If you add the script to the jQuery library as Jbadminton has above (first line in HTML). It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a class `active` to your link when you are clicking it, so your active class selector should be `.topnav a.active`

In you Fiddle, you have marked the active state using `.topnav a:hover, .topnav a:active` which is incorrect

```js
$(".topnav .topnav-centered a").on("click", function () {
  $(".topnav .topnav-centered a").removeClass();
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #1d297b;
  border: 1px solid #1d297b;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Luxia-Display";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.topnav a:hover,
.topnav a.active {
  color: #000 !important;
  border-color: #dacd9d !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have an idea why It is working when the link is `<a href="#">Link</a>` but when I put actual link like `<a hreg="page.php"> Page </a>` it's not working anymore?

Comment: @Goro Does the page refresh after selecting the link?

Comment: `#` does not link to a page and will trigger the `on click` (jQuery) to add the class to the element, that is why it works, as soon as you navigate to `page.php` you are navigating to a different page so the jQuery will trigger and then navigate away and you probably won't see the css change. You would need additional javascript/jQuery code to work out what page you were on and mark the element as active based on the current page. This would also make your `on click` code redundant.

Comment: @Nitheesh, yes, it goes to another page

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Fiddle, your JS function is adding the active class but you don't have an active class in your CSS. Make sure to add that class and additional properties needed. Something as simple as:

```js
$(".topnav .topnav-centered a").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active')
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active')
})
```

```css
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #1d297b;
  border: 1px solid #1d297b;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Luxia-Display", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
  border-color: #dacd9d !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}

a.active {
  color: #000 !important;
  border-color: #dacd9d !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav">
  <div class="topnav-centered">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Us</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He has `.topnav a:hover, .topnav a.active {` the a.active is an active class that is used.